# Not able to click on Radio button where radio button change order on the web ui page Selenium Web Driver Java

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on radio button which change order on the ui page. But there is one thing is fixed that the radio button that I want to click is next to text `"Reissue ID Card"`

Following is Web page HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="gridcell">
<tr class="gridcell">
<tr class="gridcell">
<td valign="bottom" style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(160, 160, 160);">
<td width="51" align="center" style="width:46px;">
<input id="rdbSelectAction" type="radio" onclick="fnRowSelected(this);" value="37089~8/8/2018 12:00:00 AM" name="rdbSelectAction" oldchecked="false">
</td>
<td width="140"> Reissue ID Card </td>
<td width="82"> 8/6/2012 8:07:15 AM </td>
<td width="82"> 8/8/2018 12:00:00 AM </td>
<td width="89"> Directory 2018 </td>
<td width="94"> Closed Unsuccessful - Need to Reissue ID Card Closed Unsucc </td>
<td width="103"> Admin </td>
<td width="78"> 6578 </td>
<td width="129"> 91890 </td>
<td width="330"> 000004503701/01/2012 </td>
```

I am using following xpath created from above HTML but no luck:

```
 //tr[contains(@class, 'gridcell')]/td[contains(text(), 'Reissue ID Card')]
```

Comment: Why do you want to select something 'which is next to' something? Can't you use your locator to find by `id` ? Do the `id` keep changing?

Comment: Because, Radio button with the text "Reissue ID Card" change it's position from 1,2,3 when user search different id.

Answer (score 0):

Store your elements into a list and find a perfect match and click on your elements.

```
 WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("Your Xpath"));
    String radioButtonName = "Reissue ID Card";
    List<WebElement> listRadioButton = driver.findElements(radioButton);
                System.out.println("List of Radio Buttons are available " + listRadioButton);
                Iterator<WebElement> iter = listRadioButton.iterator();
                System.out.println("Iterator Print" + iter);
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    WebElement we = iter.next();
                    System.out.println("Web Element We " + we.getText());
                    if (we.getText().equals(radioButtonName)) {
                        we.click();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created following xpath from HTML available in the above question and I am able to click on dynamic position changing radio button.:

```
//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Reissue ID Card')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/*[@id='rdbSelectAction']
```

Comment: Sounds like you could have just used `findElement(By.id("rdbSelectAction"))`? Same as what @nitinchawda said above.

Comment: SiKing - Suggestion from @nitinchawda won't work as I mentioned that it's dynamic radio button and for all available radio button id is same as rdbSelectAction so it will not select the radio button that I wanted to select. And just letting you know that all available locator for example name, class, id are same for all 6 available radio button.